# How to fix 'Unable to symlink' error from using venv on Mac Os X and Google Drive File Stream

Tags: python, python-venv

The command below will result in different outputs depending if I'm working from a folder on my Desktop or from a Google Drive File Stream folder

Here is the command:

```
python3 -m venv env
```

If the folder I'm working from is a Google Drive File Stream folder I get the following error message:

```
Unable to symlink '/usr/local/bin/python3' to '/Volumes/GoogleDrive/Mon Drive/perso/coding/Python/Environments/env/bin/python3'
```

But if I do the same from a folder located on my Desktop I got no error message and I can activate/deactivate the venv without any issues at all.

I assume this is somehow related to specific user permissions but I would appreciate your input as I'd rather not mess things up at the OS level.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the --copies (--always-copy on python2) argument. This will avoid symlinking altogether.